# Form Validation: Cancel and return w/o error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've added a validation function to my search bar to catch empty submissions.

If I use `form_set_error()` though I'll end up at the search results page with the form element highlighted.

What I actually want to happen is to just abort the submission and come back to the original page like nothing happened.

Does FAPI have a way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to handle that by conditionally adding a [#redirect](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect) attribute to the form.